# Trying to collect data between multiple <td></td>, but cant get it because no class references the data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The HTML is more complex than i know how to handle. Below is the code that is pulling the data that i need to collect.

```
title = soup.find_all('tr',attrs={'class':'cM'})
first = title[0]
first
```

[image]

i can get the title of the movie with the below code:

```
#movie title
first.find(attrs={'class':'cI'}).text
```

But, the below data (year, rating, rate, rotten tomatoe) is what i am having trouble collecting and i am not sure what class or reference i need to call to get it.

```
<td>2017</td><td>13+</td><td>7.9</td><td>92%</td>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr class="cM c2" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="//schema.org/ListItem"><td class="cH"><a href="/movie/thor-ragnarok-2017"><div class="d9 cN"><picture class="eT"><source srcset="https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-92.webp 92w,https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-154.webp 154w,https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-185.webp 185w,https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-342.webp 342w" type="image/webp"/><source srcset="https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-92.jpg 92w,https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-154.jpg 154w,https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-185.jpg 185w,https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-342.jpg 342w" type="image/jpeg"/><img alt="Watch Thor: Ragnarok" class="eU" data-async-image="true" decoding="async" src="https://img.reelgood.com/content/movie/19dcfe68-dc06-43ea-9c44-42255e780898/poster-342.jpg"/></picture></div></a></td><td class="cI"><a href="/movie/thor-ragnarok-2017">Thor: Ragnarok</a><meta content="https://reelgood.com/movie/thor-ragnarok-2017" itemprop="url"><meta content="1" itemprop="position"/></meta></td><td class="cJ"></td><td>2017</td><td>13+</td><td>7.9</td><td>92%</td><td class="cT"><span class="cU"><div class="hp cV"><img alt="netflix" src="https://img.reelgood.com/source-logos/netflix.svg"/></div></span><span class="cX">+ <!-- -->Rent or Buy</span><span><span class="cW"></span></span></td><td class="c0"></td><td class="cO"><div class="cP"><div><span>Want To See</span><img alt="Want To See Icon" src="/assets/f4b0d8c.svg" title="Add movie to watchlist"/></div><div class="cR"><span>Seen</span><img alt="Check Mark Icon" src="/assets/963fd9c.svg" title="Mark movie as seen"/></div></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML string in the question?

Comment: i was trying, but it kept just posting some text and then links, while removing all the other HTML

Comment: thats why i added the picture

Comment: You can use the `{}` button to format the html

Comment: i posted it but it is all on one line.

Comment: Well then get yourself one of them fancy new keyboards that have one of those magic [enter] keys …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findNext("td")`

**Ex:**

```
print( first.find(attrs={'class':'cI'}).text )
print( first.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext("td").text )
print( first.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext("td").findNext("td").text )
print( first.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext("td").findNext("td").findNext("td").text )
print( first.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext("td").findNext("td").findNext("td").findNext("td").text )
```

*If you do not want to repeat the code*

```
print( first.find(attrs={'class':'cI'}).text )
obj = first.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'})
if obj:
    for i in range(4):
        obj = obj.findNext("td")
        if obj:
            print( obj.text )
```

**Output:**

```
Thor: Ragnarok
2017
13+
7.9
92%
```